# android: how do i measure the traffic my smartphone produces?

Tags: android, sdk, traffic

i need to monitor, which services/apps produce what traffic (measured in kbit/s, separated by up- and downlink) for my phone. how do i do this? i googled around but did not find any helpful posts/howtos...

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to get so much detailed info. However, this is the starting point anyway: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the class TrafficStats :)
Here, you can get the transferred Bytes and/or packages...