# Any way to figure out bytes sent/recvd over a data connection on Android?

Tags: android, logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: how do i measure the traffic my smartphone produces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455854/android-how-do-i-measure-the-traffic-my-smartphone-produces)

I was just wondering if android logs the bytes sent/recvd over a data connection somewhere. I was trying to play around with logcat, but could'nt get anything much (Im sure Ive missing something considering this is the first time im playing around with it).

Also I understand logcat is a circular log, so does that mean old logs simply get purged or is it backed-up somewhere ? I was hoping to get usage statistics of my data connectivity over the past week or so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @haimg i was looking for a slighly non-sdk solution.. but I'll tinker with it.. Also, the API requires the process UID. do u have a solution that tracks total bytes across a network connection and a give time slice ?

Answer (score 3):

> I was just wondering if android logs the bytes sent/recvd over a data connection somewhere.

As pointed out in the comment, the answer is to use `TrafficStats`.

> I was trying to play around with logcat, but could'nt get anything much (Im sure Ive missing something considering this is the first time im playing around with it).

Data transfers are not recorded in LogCat.

> Also I understand logcat is a circular log, so does that mean old logs simply get purged or is it backed-up somewhere ?

By definition, a ring buffer like LogCat uses purges old records to make room for new ones.

> I was hoping to get usage statistics of my data connectivity over the past week or so.

Record it yourself within your application via `TrafficStats`. Or create a separate application that runs and records the data via `TrafficStats`, such as [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor).

> Also, the API requires the process UID.

Not all the methods on `TrafficStats` require a UID.

> do u have a solution that tracks total bytes across a network connection and a give time slice ?

Use `getTotalRxBytes()` and `getTotalTxBytes()`.